# React can't find a module after converting to .tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, module

i'm having this trouble while trying to convert a react app to typescript.

After creating the app with npx create-react-app and creating the components (and make them work), i decided to convert them to tsx.

So i installed typescript with `npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest` as said in the documentation.

Then, i added a tsconfig file, which contains that:

`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ],
  "types": ["typePatches"]
}
```

`

Then, i proceded to rename my .js files to .tsx .

Now, to simplify, let's imagine that i created only a dumb Button component like that:
`

```
import React from "react";

const Button: React.FC = () => {
  return <button>Hello</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

`

and imported it in my index.js:

`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Button from "./Button";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Button />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`

when i restart my server i get this error:
`Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/index.js
Module not found: ./Button in C:...path\src

@ ./src/index.js 21:14-33`

and this is my package.json just in case:
`

```
{
  "name": "mern-user-crud-location",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "^0.9.5",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

`

I DON'T have any webpack.config!

I tried almost everything that i found on Stack Overflow and the internet in general but nothing seems to solve this problem.

I tried do add .tsx at the end of the component path and i get no errors but then the component stop working.

Can you please help me?

Comment: `index.js`?,  did you not rename this to `index.ts`?  And of course you have at some point run `tsc`?

Comment: i guess i can't rename it to .ts since it contains jsx. i tried to rename it to .tsx tho, and i still get the same error

Comment: The error says -> `Error in ./src/index.js`  It's trying to compile a `.js` file, it's this I'm talking about, if it's got JSX, then make it `index.tsx`..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your  tsconfig.json file in `compilerOptions`.

```
            "paths": {
                "*": [
                    "*",
                    "components/*"
                ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately i still get the error